# How to trigger mouseover on a different element for a mouseover on an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I have added a `mouseover` event on the button. In that event, I am calling the `mouseover` event on the anchor. However, that anchor `mouseover` is not properly triggered. I am not able to see the URL preview at the bottom left corner, like I could see if I hover the over the anchor element. How could I properly trigger mouseover on an anchor?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $("button.pdfbutton").mouseover(function(e) {
    $("#anchorelem").show();
    $("#anchorelem").mouseover();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="pdfbutton">PDF</button>
<a href="https://google.com" id="anchorelem" style="display: none;">Some text</a>
```

Comment: Even when you trigger a mouse event on the `a` element you won't see the browsers URL preview appear. If you want that behaviour you'll need to restructure your HTML to rely on actual user-generated events instead of programmatically created ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button.pdfbutton").mouseover(function(e) {
    $("#anchorelem").show();
    $("#anchorelem").mouseover();
    $("#txt_lnk").bind('click', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="pdfbutton">
  <a id="txt_lnk" href="http://text-to-show" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;">PDF</a>
</button>
<a href="http://google.com" id="anchorelem" style="display: none;">Some text</a>
```

Comment: While this works (in Chrome on Win10 at least) note that it's a non-standard hack which will probably be patched out at some point. As per the `button` element spec: '... there must be no interactive content descendant.' https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The URL preview of an `<a>` element in the bottom left corner of your browser is (far as I know) not triggered by a JS event (which means you cannot trigger it by calling `mouseover()`). It is just browser native functionality. If you want to show the preview I would suggest one of the following:

1. Create an `<a>` element and style it to look like a regular button. Then when someone hovers over it, they will see the link it leads to.
2. Create some other hidden element that contains a text you want to display when the user hovers over the button. Then set up the button to show that element when the user hovers over that button.